# Correct position of choke

Tags: automatic-transmission

My bike is Yamaha saluto RX 110cc.  I confused about the choke position whether it is up lever or down lever guide me

Comment: Take the air inlet pipe off and check the butterfly position cf the lever position.

Answer (score 1):

The choke restricts the air, making the mixture rich, and is used to help the engine in cold starts. Therefore, when the engine is cold applying choke will increase the engine RPM. So, whichever direction makes the rev count go up on a cold start is the direction in which choke is applied.